# Page Flickering effect on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, scroll

The page flickers on scroll, it works fine in Firefox but not in chrome. I tried disabling the chrome smooth scroll plugin but still doesn't work.

Comment: welcome provide more information and read this too https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you give us the link of your web page so we can check to at our end.?

Comment: try this https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0dHOer4tkalU/?hl=en&msgid=cuWnsSwJAwAJ&gpf=d/msg/chrome/dHOer4tkalU/cuWnsSwJAwAJ

Comment: https://www.lakme-academy.com/

Comment: Hi @vanita ;) don't use the comments to bring additional information, just edit your original post instead. Also it would be nice to tell us how you got there, this is probably caused by a javascript or css feature, so depending on what recently changed on your site and since when the issue has been around, it might be easier to spot what is really causing this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the source code and search for *'scroll'*, you will find the following event bindings (unminified & beautified) :

```
$window.bind('scroll').resize();

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        };
        $("html").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("html").scrollTop() + (-delta * 1.7)
        }, 200, 'linear');
    }
});
```

The resize on scroll is a weird thing, but the second binding is definitely nonsense and is the one causing the issue :

- every tiny scroll animation will be interrupted `$("html").stop()`
- and overridden with a contradictory scroll animation `.animate({scrollTop: $("html").scrollTop() + (-delta * 1.7)})`

Before commenting/deleting this code, just unbind from the chrome console to check :

```
jQuery(window).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
```

Comment: Worked as charm